# Invalid Date error when entering record on Sharepoint list Datasheet view

Tags: date, datetime, sharepoint

I have a list on Sharepoint 2013. I've often use the Edit this list link to make bulk changes to the list in datasheet view with no problem. Last week I had a bunch of new records I needed to add so decided bulk copy and paste from Excel would be best. However, I get the error "Invalid date/time value. A date/time field contains invalid data. Please check the value and try again." The field is Date/Time with Date only display. The format I copied in was mm/dd/yyyy, which is how it's displayed (I realize there's a difference between formatting and display). In the past I've used this format to update dates with no problem. I've tried manually changing the date to other formats like yyyy/mm/dd (or with dashes -), and using the date picker and nothing works. I can add a new item using the form and no problem with the date. It's only happening in datasheet view.

I have 70+ records to add and would rather not have to open a new form for each one (I'm only adding info to 7 of the fields, and I first only pasted a couple records to make sure there were no issues). Are there any recent known issues about date fields in datasheet view? It's a pretty straightforward thing, no calculations are being used, I'm not trying to connect to another service, or use outlying dates (dates are all 2017) so I'm perplexed why this is an issue now and not before. Any thoughts on this would be appreciated.

Comment: I've also tried leaving the date off and still get the error.

Comment: Have you tried copying the fields of one row one by one to determine exactly which field is giving you the issue?

Comment: Yes, tried that. I get the error with just data in the first field, which is a string. I've also tried taking the date field out of the view and still get the error.

Comment: What happens when you create a new item? via the New item OOTB functionality? Can you see any differences with the data you are pasting in to manual creation of one of the rows?

Comment: OOTB new item opens a form. I can enter data that way, one record at a time, and save it no problem. I'm not seeing any differences in the data from one method to another. It's quite specific in that it's only new items in bulk edit that have issues. I can edit existing records and save no problem. And it's just this list. I created a new list and was able to copy and paste date data in bulk edit with no issues. I'm thinking maybe that date field is corrupted?

Comment: Found the issue. I had another date field I was not using in that view that for some reason the default value had been set to Calculated field with a value of 1/1/1111. No idea how that got there but I removed that and set the default value to None and now the problem is gone. I found it by creating a new view with every date field in the list and systematically copying a date into each field (in bulk edit) and trying to save after each one until it saved.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. I had another date field I was not using in that view that for some reason the default value had been set to Calculated field with a value of 1/1/1111. No idea how that got there but I removed that and set the default value to None and now the problem is gone. I found it by creating a new view with every date field in the list and systematically copying a date into each field (in bulk edit) and trying to save after each one until it saved. Then I checked the settings for the field that I was able to save with.